# webproxy.exe process causing 100% CPU usage

Tags: windows-7, process, cpu-usage, webproxy

today I found that my laptop's fan is worked in full level. after checking `performance` tab in `task manager` I see CPU usage is 100% and not change. I see `webproxy.exe` process in top of `resource monitor` list and everytime I end this process, after 1 second it run again.

[image]

I searched for it but can't find any help. I just suspend it for help my dear CPU.

- **OS :** windows 7 Professional
- **Arch. :** x64

Comment: Do you use Web Freer program or Such this? go to task manager - in proccess tab click on show proccess from all user and in name column find WebClientService and stop that , then EndTask webproxy.exe then go to programfile/YourBrowser and delete webproxy.exe then start WebClientService  in task manager, I hope to be useful for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a zip code, name it webproxy.exe, replace it with the real webproxy.exe file in C:/windows/syswow64 folder or where ever that is, in the safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem since I installed the "Web Freer".
It also copied the "**webproxy.exe**" file in the "**C:\Windows\SysWOW64**" location and even when I uninstalled the program, it ran it from there, so you may need to delete it by yourself from there too. It may help preventing the same problem again.